# C - Null Terminating char doesnt stop printing

Tags: c, strcat, null-terminated

in this part of code:

```
char* data;
char num[10];

sprintf(num, "%d", 260);
strcat(data, num);
strcat(data, "\0");

sprintf(num, "%d", 130);
strcat(data, num);

sprintf(num, "%d", 128);
strcat(data, num);

printf("Data: %s", data);
```

it's printing:

```
Data: 260130128
```

Why does this happen? The null terminator character shouldnt terminate the printing?

Thank you

**Edits:**

1. The data has been initialized before, I am getting it from a function.
2. Why does not print only 260? How can I do it?

Comment: `data` has not been initialised

Comment: You don't need to append the null character manually, `strcat` already does this and `strcat(data, "\0");` does absolutely nothing (not to mention the string literal itself is also null-terminated, so it contains two null chars in this case). What you need to do is initialize `data` to something which can hold all these values.

Comment: You probably need to read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: Fix your code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lurker edited, sorry!

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: ... and what exactly should be the content of the memory `data` points to?

Comment: @NickStavr This is a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Step back and think what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. Then [edit] your question or may just ask another question

Comment: the pointer `data` is not initialized, so it points using what ever trash happened to be on the stack at its' location.  Accessing the memory where the `data` points (since it is uninitialized) is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: suggest reading/understanding the MAN page about `strcat()`

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 crucial problems with your code.

Firstly, `data` isn't initialised. It's just pointing at some random point in memory. You should either allocate some memory to store it using `malloc` like

```
char *data=malloc(200);
```

or just declare it as an array like you've done with `num`.

```
char data[200];
```

Secondly, when you first `strcat` into `data`, it's not NUL terminated so you're appending potentially into random garbage data. You can either replace that first `strcat` with a `strcpy` (which makes the most sense)

```
strcpy(data, num);
```

or make sure that `data[0]` equals `\0`

```
data[0]='\0';
strcat(data,num);
```

You don't need to do `strcat(data, "\0");` as `strcat` and `strcpy` will ensure that `data` is correctly NUL terminated.

Comment: Even when I do data[3]='\0', after inserting 260, it doesnt change anything..

(Its not "260\0130128"?)

Comment: @NickStavr _Its not "260\0130128_ how do you know?

Comment: @NickStavr Why would it be that? If `data` contains "260\0" - you add on "130" and it becomes "260130\0"

Comment: if I replace data[3]='\0' with data[3]='!', the output is  "260!130128"

Comment: @NickStavr the `\0` is where the string ends, if you add more characters to it with `strcat`, the end moves. a '!' is a regular character so will be a part of the string. Although unless you also added `data[4]='\0'` your string would be unterminated and cause problems.

Comment: the real question is how can i place the \0 in the middle
or what can i place in the middle of 260 and 130 to stop printing after 260

Comment: It's like if you have a shelf of books with one end propped up by a book end. As you add books to the shelf, you move the book end along. If you remove the book end, the books fall over. The book end isn't considered a book.

Comment: If you want to terminate the string in the middle, you need to put the `data[3]='\0'` after you've finished constructing the string, like before the `printf`

Answer (score 3):

No. `strcat` removes the trailing nul character before appending.

Reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy` to copy the substring into your buffer after the existing data+NUL. Because you're basically putting multiple strings into a buffer you'll have to keep track of the total length of the data in the buffer yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  char data[100] = "";
  char num[10];
  int  data_len = 0;

  sprintf(num, "%d", 260);
  strcpy(data+data_len, num);
  data_len += strlen(num)+1; 

  sprintf(num, "%d", 130);
  strcpy(data+data_len, num);
  data_len += strlen(num)+1;

  sprintf(num, "%d", 128);
  strcpy(data+data_len, num);
  data_len += strlen(num)+1;

  printf("data_len = %d\n", data_len);
  printf("Data: %s\n", data);
  }
```

Best of luck.